# Objects not detecting each other?

Tags: python, game-engine

I have a sensor object that I need to execute a certain function once it detects a certain static object. Everything works, except it *always* has difficulty detecting it. The only way to make it *guaranteed* to work is if I scale the static object by an absurd number, this way it will always collide; however, I can't have my object be so large! Is there any way to fix this issue and have my sensor object detect the static object consistently? Thanks!

Comment: Share the blend file if you can, and check if any info here helps you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34155/do-ray-sensors-detect-collision-bounds

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31579/near-radar-ray-collision-sensors-refuse-to-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collisions detect intersections of faces only.

If your object is "inside" the over object without intersecting any face it can't be sensed.

[image]

If you want this kind of detection you need to ensure the sensing object has no gap that a sensed object could "hide" without touching a face (and vice versa).

The background is simple: The physics engine does not perform "inside" checks. It assumes that objects will intersect a surface before being inside another object. This is for performance reasons. Unfortunately small fast travelling objects can do exactly that.

[image]

A possible solution for you is to add additional faces inside the surrounding object.

[image]